# Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación escritorio Java SE con Maven Netbeans, Hibernate y Spring Framework para IoC.

Al correr me devuelve este error(copiado mas abajo), al parecer no logra construir el Bean sessionFactory declarado dentro de mi AplicationContext.xml, no se si sera problemas entre versiones

**** CONFIGURACION DEL sessionFactory EN APLICATIONCONTEXT.xml****

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <!--        LLAMADO A CONEXION A FUENTE DE DATOS-->
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>

        <!--        PROPIEDADES DE HIBERNATE-->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <!--        MAPEO DE ENTIDADES-->
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>datos/hibernate/orm/MiTabla.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

*****COPIO EL MENSAJE DE ERROR**************

> ADVERTENCIA: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
>   Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;